# How to change the default Magento Shopping Cart URL

Tags: url-rewrite, shopping-cart

I would like to change the shopping cart URL from `/checkout/cart/` to `/checkout/bag/`. Is it possible to modify the default URL, and if so, how?

Comment: can you refer to this page to check the solution... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722841/custom-url-for-magentos-basket-page

Answer (score 0):

Skovy,it possible but it not good for health,You need override of CartController.php with Your Controller Bagcontroller.php.Also need change the  helper class from where cart url id define .

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
    <Amit_Customcontacts>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Amit_Customcontacts>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <contacts>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <customcontacts before="Mage_Checkout">Amit_Customcontacts</customcontacts>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </contacts>
        </routers>
    </frontend>  
<global>
        <!-- This rewrite rule could be added to the database instead -->
        <rewrite>
            <!-- This is an identifier for your rewrite that should be unique -->
            <!-- THIS IS THE CLASSNAME IN YOUR OWN CONTROLLER -->
            <customcontactsunique>
                <from><![CDATA[#^/checkout/cart/#]]></from>
                <!--
                    - mymodule matches the router frontname below
                    -  matches the path to your controller

                    Considering the router below, "/customcontacts/cart/" will be
                    "translated" to "app/code/local/Amit/Customcontacts/controllers/BagController.php" (?)
                -->
                <to>/checkkout/bag/</to>
            </customcontactsunique>
        </rewrite>
    </global>    

</config>
```